# Django - Pre populate form with instance data

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have the following class based view,

```
class FacetUpdate(TenantRootedMixin, UpdateView):
  model = Tenant
  context_object_name = 'facetten'
  form_class = FacetForm

  def get_success_url(self):
      kwargs = {'uuid': self.object.uuid}
      return reverse_lazy('productupdate', kwargs=kwargs)


  def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
      return reverse('facet_list', args=[self.request.tenant.slug])


  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      d = super(FacetUpdate, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
      self.object = self.get_object()
      return super(FacetUpdate, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)


  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      d = super(FacetUpdate, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
      self.object = self.get_object()
      #Create list of selected checkbox_ids
      hitlist = request.POST.getlist('facet_link')
      #Get current tenant
      currenttenant = Tenant.objects.get(name=self.request.tenant)
      #Get all facets that have been selected in the form
      selected_facets = Facetss.objects.filter(id__in=hitlist)
      #Update the currenttenant
      currenttenant.linked_facets = selected_facets
      currenttenant.save()
      return d
```

That passes data to the following form.

```
class FacetForm(forms.ModelForm):


  class Meta:
      model = Tenant
      fields = ['linked_facets']
```

This form is not using an autogenerated form, but a custom html page that contains a list of checkboxes. (Using a default widget meant that the layout was all wrong, as we wanted a nested layout)

The form works, however, the one thing that is missing is having the checkboxes being prepopulated based on the instance that is being edited. 
All fields in the form show up empty, forcing the user to rewrite all of the data during the edit process.

When I was using function based views I had to define an 'instance' in the view, which would then load all of the relevant data. Yet I am having trouble creating something simular for the class based view that I am currently working on.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

EDIT:

I've included the html page that I use for the form below

```
 {% extends "layouts/tabbed_panel.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load mptt_tags %}

{% block panel-header %}
    <h1 class="text-primary">Facetten Aanpassen</h1>
{% endblock %}


{% block panel-body %}
<form action="." method="POST" class="FacetForm">{% csrf_token %}
        <ul id="id_linked_facets">
        {% recursetree facetten %}
            <li>
                <label><input type="checkbox" name= 'facet_link' value={{node.pk}}><strong>{{ node.name }}</strong></label>



                {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                    <ul class="children">
                        {{ children }}
                    </ul>



                {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endrecursetree %}
        </ul>
        <br>
        <div class="text-right">
            <a href="{% url 'facet_list' tenant.slug %}" class="btn btn-default">{% block cancel-button-text %}{% trans "Cancel" %}{% endblock %}</a>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" />
        </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

EDIT 2:

Based on some of the comments (THANKS!) I' ve eddited the view's 'GET'  function like so.

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      d = super(FacetUpdate, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
      currenttenant = self.context.tenant
      d['linked_facets'] = currenttenant.linked_facets
      self.object = self.get_object()
      return d
```

When I print this to the terminal the value seems to show up, but I am still unclear on how to pass this to the actual template. I'm sorry if I' m missing something very obvious, I still need to get my head around class based views.

Comment: If you're using a "custom HTML page" to show your checkboxes, presumably you need to do something there to populate them? Maybe you should show that template...

Comment: Good call, I've editted my post to include the HTML page that I use for the form.

Comment: You're not using the form to display anything in your template, so you have to make sure your context is populated with the correct data. In your case, both in the get and in the post request, you need to add your facet_links (or your object as returned by get_object) to the context for rendering your template.

Comment: By the way, even if not using the widgets provided by the form fields, I would still use the form data to populate the template. You can still use things like `form.facet_links.id_for_label` and `form.facet_links.values` etc...

Comment: Could you give me an example on how to do that? 
I' ve  added the relevant values to both the GET, POST and Get_Context functions, but the view still is not passing the relvant variables.

Comment: Just to clarify: `<input type="checkbox" name= 'facet_link' value={{node.pk}}>` is what needs to be checked if the value is already set on the instance? In that case, you'll need to add a `{% if facet_link == node.pk %}checked{%endif%}` statement (or something similar, it's not clear where your variables come from) to use the variables in your context.

Comment: Hi dirkgroten, 

Yeah, the data is comning from the MPTT module - which is somewhat byzantine in how everything works. However, using your example I was able to solve the problem! Many thanks! I will update my question to reflect the solution I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your replies! (And dirkgroten in particular) 
The fact that I was using the MPTT module made everything more complicated, but with your help I was able to solve the problem by by making 2 changes:

In the view I added a get_context_data:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    d = super(FacetUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    currenttenant = self.context.tenant
    d['linked_facets'] = currenttenant.linked_facets.all()
    print("CONTEXT", d)
    return d
```

I then used the 'linked_facets'  value in the template to check if the box should be checked (slightly changed from dirkgroten his advice)

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name= 'facet_link' {% if node in linked_facets %}checked{%endif%} value={{node.pk}}><strong>{{ node.name }}</strong></label>
```

Many thanks everyone, this problem has been bugging me for hours now and it is finaly solved!